# Doubts on correct BDD approach in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, tdd, bdd

I am doing BDD in the following way:

> -> Creating Cucumber scenarios (for Integrational tests) 
>   -> Create the needed Model Rspe Unit tests
>
> --> Back to the Cucumber scenarios.

However, I have heard that it is nice to also test the Controller by using Unit testing (for example with Rspec).  I am wondering if this is a good idea, or it is "too much" for testing.  For example, the famous [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/), doesn't do Controller tests, it just do Integration tests (with Rspec directly) and Model Unit tests (also with Rspec).

So, any advice on this? What is a good approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, of course, a pretty debated issue, but here's an important blog post detailing the arguments FOR testing controllers:

http://solnic.eu/2012/02/02/yes-you-should-write-controller-tests.html